# Out of all the required columns in a Sharepoint list, why does only the "Title" column have a required asterisk(*) next to it in the Edit/New form?

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-online

I created an Equipment Log list on Sharepoint Online that has four required columns:

- Last Name
- First Name
- Start Date
- Item (renamed from the default Title)

when I want to Edit an item or add a New item, only the "Title" column is showing with an asterisk(*) next to it on the edit form.

When I leave the 3 required columns (except Title/Item) blank, a new record gets inserted into the list but the columns have pink colored boxes with "Required info" text.

When I leave Title blank on the Edit form and click Save, I get this validation message
"An entry is required or has an invalid value. Please correct and try again."

How come I do not get the same validation message for the other 3 required fields?

Thank you.

[new item form with only the Title column with an asterisk](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mrebP.jpg)

[new record with missing  3 required columns](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oxQRy.jpg)

Comment: Could you post some images? i am trying to replicate the issue on my end but am unsuccessful.

Comment: Hi Manny. I added two screenshots to my post. The first one is a screenshot of the new record form, with only the Title column having an asterisk and getting validated. The second screenshot is a new record with the missing 3 required columns

Comment: I think to duplicate this we need to 1) create a  list but do not specify the required columns 2) add some records 3) then edit the list description and  make 3 of the 4 columns required. If you create the list and set the required fields before you enter any records, you do not see the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I could reproduce this when setting a column to a required column, the old items would show "Required info" if there's no value in this field. This is by design behavior, which reminds you that column is changed to a required column.

Besides, it's by default that the Title column is a required column when we create a list. You could change this in this way: go to list settings-> click the column Title, select no for "Require that this column contains information". Like this:

[image]

Comment: Yes,  but when I want to add a record or edit a record, that column that I just set to Require Information does not have an asterisk next to it and when I leave it blank,  I do not get a validation error message. Have you encountered this problem as well?

Comment: No, I never met this. If I set the column to require information, It would have an asterisk next to it.

Comment: Are you able to duplicate the problem by following these 3 steps ?        
 1) create a list but do not specify the required columns    Last Name
First Name
Start Date
Item (renamed from the default Title)                                
 2) add some records                                                                                         
 3) then edit the list description and make those 3 columns required. When you try to add a new record, the asterisks do not show up and there are no validation messages for those 3 required columns.